# Corenlp in hadoop : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, hadoop, garbage-collection, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to run corenlp in hadoop and getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded.

I have tried to increase heap size but no result. Here is edits in my hadoo_env.sh file

```
export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=20000
HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS="-Dsecurity.audit.logger=ERROR,DRFAS -Xmx10g $HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS "
export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Xmx5g ${HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS}"
```

Comment: did you get the solution ?

Comment: Initially my input data was in chunks of 15 GB, I reduced the input data chunk sizes to 10 GB and it worked. My memory requirement for each worker was 6 GB (default memory upper limit in hadoop is 128 MB). There were too many worker threads spawned in the first case thus hadoop was unable to allocate that much memory.  When I reduced input data size then it had less number of workers so memory allocation was not an issue.

Comment: thanks for replying , i have one worker only and data a round 12 GB did you use storm before ?

Comment: No, I never tried storm.

Comment: thanks for replying and helping